# Parse JavaScript variable with Python

Tags: javascript, python, variables

How can I convert a JavaScript variable (not JSON format) into a python variable?

Example JavaScript variable:

```
{
    title: "TITLE",
    name: "NAME",
    active: false,
    info: {
        key1: "value1",
        dict1: {
            sub_key1: "sub_value1",
            sub_key2: "sub_value2",
        },
        dict2: {
            sub_key3: "sub_value3",
            sub_key4: "sub_value4",
            sub_key5: "sub_value5"
        },
    },
    list1: ["element1", "element2", "element2"],
}
```

Comment: You might want to say if that "Javascript variable" is stored in a Python string or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This format looks just like the input in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601864/python-load-text-as-python-object/3602436#3602436).  Try adapting the pyparsing parser I posted there.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to JSON and read it in python.

I really do not understand what is the problem?

e.g. `JSON.stringify` gives

```
{"title":"TITLE","name":"NAME","active":false,"info":{"key1":"value1","dict1":{"sub_key1":"sub_value1","sub_key2":"sub_value2"},"dict2":{"sub_key3":"sub_value3","sub_key4":"sub_value4","sub_key5":"sub_value5"}},"list1":["element1","element2","element2"]}
```

Which can be read by python json module, so question is where from you are getting javascript and why can't you convert it to JSON?

Edit: if the source of javascript if totally out of your control, you can use javascript as a command line scripting language e.g. [spidermonkey](http://www.mozilla.org/js/spidermonkey/) (used in firefox), [rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/), [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) (used in google chrome) or on windows WSH. Using javascript interpreter you can modify javascript , stringify it and then process it with python if needed.

It is better to user already implemented and tested interpreter than to build one by yourselves.

You can also try [python-spidermonkey](http://code.google.com/p/python-spidermonkey/)

Comment: how can I stringify a Javascript variable to JSON string in Python? I cannot control the format of the source variable. It appears exactly as listed above in a .html file.